# Convert Sql Table to XML

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table Users with three Columns: Id, Username, Email.

I need to convert it to XML in the following format:

```
 <Table Name="Users">
      <Column Name='Id'>1</Column>
      <Column Name='Username'>user1</Column>
      <Column Name='Email'>user1@gmail.com</Column>
 </Table>
 <Table Name="Users">
      <Column Name='Id'>2</Column>
      <Column Name='Username'>user2</Column>
      <Column Name='Email'>user2@gmail.com</Column>
 </Table>
```

Until now, I have written this:

```
select * from Users for xml raw('Table'), Elements, type
```

which gives me this result:

```
 <Table>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Username>user1</Username>
      <Email>user1@gmail.com</Email>
 </Table>
 <Table>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Username>user2</Username>
      <Email>user2@gmail.com</Email>
 </Table>
```

Comment: If you can't get SQL Server to do that then it should be relatively easy to post-process that into the form you want, but I don't know XSLT very well. How to hierarchies of objects look, both as-is and in the form you want - is that going to be harder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'Users' as [@Name],
        (select 'Id'       as [@Name], Id       as '*' for xml path('Column'), type),
        (select 'Username' as [@Name], Username as '*' for xml path('Column'), type),
        (select 'Email'    as [@Name], Email    as '*' for xml path('Column'), type)
from Users
for xml path('Table'), type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be7ac/1)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if an xsl solution is appropriate here.  If it is the following would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="AllUsers">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Table" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <Column>
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">     
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /> 
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </Column>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, AllUsers is the root node of the source xml.